# Операторы преобразования типов

Tags: c++

В чем преимущество преобразователей типов `static_cast` и `dynamic_cast` перед старым сишным способом приведения типов и в каких случаях их применение совершенно необходимо, т.е. старый способ приводит к ошибке или невозможен?

Answer (score 4):

```
struct A
{
    int i;
}

struct B
{
    float f;
}

A* a = new A;
B* b = (B*)a;

b->f = 123.456
```

При записи значения будет затронута память не принадлежащая переменной класса A, т.к.

```
sizeof(float) > sizeof(int)
```

Такое преобразование не безопасно, поэтому и были добавлены операторы пребразование типов, они перекладывают работу по определению корректно ли преобразование типов с програмиста на компилятор (что не может не радовать=)

http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/qt_software/106294/

Comment: >sizeof(float) > sizeof(int)

 ЧЕГО??? У них размер одинаковый - 4 байта.

Comment: Смотря где. На многих платформах (в т.ч. x86 16бит) sizeof(int) == 2, sizeof(float) == 4

Comment: @alexlz, Вы бы еще ламповые ЭВМ вспомнили.

Comment: @KARTOH, Ваш пример, если заменить float на double, показывает реальную пользу от применения этих операторов.

Comment: @mikillskegg На ламповых ЭВМ (хоть я их и не видел) Си не было. А вот что касается, скажем, восьми(шестнадцати)разрядных микроконтроллеров, то эти звери могут быть вполне современными. И трансляторы с Си там тоже довольно свежие.

Comment: Вряд ли автор ответа имеет в виду микроконтроллеры.

Answer (score 1):

Большее уважение к системе типов. Сишные кастинги ставятся везде одинаково, в си-два-креста -- четыре разных, в зависимости от ситуации. И ещё, как написано у Эккеля, функциональный синтаксис устраняет ошибку определения, к чему же именно применяется кастинг. Хотя и в сишном можно добавить скобок вокруг преобразуемого значения, но этого, как правило, не делают, а тут -- деваться некуда.
**UPD** Тут [[@GLmonster](/users/4139/glmonster)](/users/4139/glmonster) обратил внимание на dynamic_cast. Это преобразование типобезопасное, при попытке downcasting'а в неподходящий тип будет 0 для указателя и исключение для ссылки (кажется). Утверждение, что сишное преобразование приводит к ошибке мне кажется неверным (если можно преобразовать -- то преобразует, если нельзя -- тоже преобразует. В отличие от dynamic_cast)

Answer (score 1):

dynamic_cast необходим, так как он учитывает полиморфизм. Приведения указателей полиморфных типов в стиле C приведут к ошибке.

Остальные типы приведения делят функциональность приведения C. Лично я считаю, что нет смысла использовать приведения в стиле C++, так как вероятность таких ошибок очень мала, а код выглядит громоздким. Мою точку зрения доказывают C# и D, в которых есть только одно приведение.

Comment: "Приведения указателей полиморфных типов в стиле C приведут к ошибке." -- откуда дровишки?

Comment: >"Приведения указателей полиморфных типов в стиле C приведут к ошибке." -- откуда дровишки?

 Естественно, приведёт к ошибке не само приведение, а обращение к объекту по этому указателю.

 У меня самого была такая ошибка. Исправил её, заменив приведение на dynamic_cast. Сделал такой вывод, потому что в С не было никакого наследования.

Comment: Странные рассуждения и непонятные. Если вы не пытаетесь привести указатель на какой-то класс к указателю на другой класс, не являющийся предком этого, то ничего страшного быть не должно. Но если пытаетесь халтурить, то dynamic_cast обидится, а сишное приведение -- нет. Хозяину, мол, видней. Если я не прав -- пример в студию (у меня фантазии не хватает). И ключевое слово тут не "наследование", а RTTI.

Comment: У меня была ошибка при приведении указателя на базовый класс к указателю на производный класс (конечно, делалась проверка, точно ли указатель указывает на объект этого класса). Решилось всё dynamic_cast'ом.

 Когда будет время, проведу эксперименты.

Comment: Непонятно. Если это был указатель на потомка, хранящийся в переменной типа "указатель на базовый класс", то при приведении к "родному" (или "промежуточному" -- предок "родного", потомок базового) указателю всё будет нормально. А иначе и dynamic_cast должен дать 0.